# Probability of getting same number

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the probability of getting the same number when spinning a roulette wheel, tossing a die, and drawing a random card?

My approach:

Case A - Get a random number on the roulette wheel, now get the same number on the die and the card: $$1 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{13} = \frac{1}{78}$$

Case B - Get a random number on the die, then get the same number on the roulette wheel and the card: $$1 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{13} = \frac{1}{78}$$

Case C - Get a random number on the card, now get the same number on the  die and the roulette wheel: $$\frac{6}{13} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{78}$$ ($\frac{6}{13}$ for the card since we can only choose the numbers $1$–$6$)

Sum all $3$ cases: $$\frac{3}{78} = \bf{\frac{1}{26}}$$

Does this seem right or I am on the wrong approach here?

Comment: Not every card or number has a match on the die.

Comment: Consider that you have a $1$ in $38$ chance of landing on any given number on the roulette wheel. Surely the odds of getting a roulette wheel, die, and card all to line up are worse than $\frac1{38},$ not better!

Comment: @Théophile I was considering a roulette wheel with 6 numbers. If I consider 38 numbers I get 1/(13*38) which makes sense. Just wondering I if my approach would be right for a roulette wheel with 6 numbers. Thanks

Comment: For a wheel with $6$ numbers, your reasoning would be correct if you stopped at Case A, for example. When you add in Cases B & C, you're overcounting. (Compare to the bigger roulette wheel solution of $\frac{1}{13\cdot38}$, not $\frac{3}{13\cdot38}$.) Cases B and C are also correct (hence the same result), it's just that you must pick one of those methods, not all three.

Comment: Here's a more appropriate way to split into cases. Suppose you draw the card first. Case X: the card value is between $1$ and $6$. Then (...). Case Y: the card value is $7$ or higher. In that case, the probability of the other items matching is $0$. These two cases are disjoint and cover all possible outcomes, so we may add them together. (This will be equivalent to your Case C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a US roulette wheel, there are 38 numbers, the die has the most restrictive ($\{1,...,6\}$) and the cards have 52 possibilities.

The total number of selections is $38 \cdot 6 \cdot 52$ and the number of selections that match is $4 \cdot 6$ so the probability is ${1 \over 13 \cdot 38}$ (about $0.2 \%$).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Slightly simpler calculation: roll the die, being the most restrictive item; then the chance the card and wheel match is $\frac1{13}\cdot\frac1{38}$.

Comment: @Théophile Yep, more succinct approach. I like brute force when dealing with probabilities, if feasible, as it reduces the number of mistakes I can make (which I do).

Comment: @copper.hat thanks a lot for the answer. not sure who downvoted, wasn't me

Comment: Sure, both ways work.